# Как в коде отличить xiaomi с MIUI и stock android

Tags: android, xiaomi

Иногда нам нужно определить производителя(manufacturer), чтобы учесть специфичную работу на его телефонах.

Мы можем обратиться к константе `Build.MANUFACTURER` и сравинть её со строкой(к примеру: "xiaomi").

Обычно этого достаточно, но возник вопрос, как отличить *Xiaomi* с *MIUI* от *Xiaomi* с *Stock Android*?

Нашёл следующий [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552878/get-android-miui-version-information-programmatically), но он кажется не слишком надёжным, о чём не забывает упомянуть автор ответа.

Приходилось ли кому-то решать подобную задачу и как вы это сделали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственная проблема с приведенным кодом, в том, что он используется недокументированный класс `android.os.SystemProperties`

Как альтернативу можно попробовать зайти с другой стороны, скажем, при вызове `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` по идее будет вызываться просмотровщик, который в оболочке MIUI будет иметь сигнатуру начинающуюся с `ro.miui`, а в гугловской будет другая сигнатура. Сказано, сделано - лепим приблизительно такой код:

```
 private boolean isMIUI(Context context) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setType("image/*"); //хотим как бы посмотреть картинки
     //получаем список всех потенциальных обработчиков нашего вью интента
     List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, MATCH_ALL);
     for (ResolveInfo ri: resInfoList) {
         if(ri.resolvePackageName!=null && 
              ri.resolvePackageName.toLowerCase().contains("miui")
             //bingo! - оболочка MIUI!
             return true;
     }
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: Для меня сработали:

Способ из описания проблемы,
Этот ответ,
И ещё есть вот такая штука: https://gist.github.com/Muyangmin/e8ec1002c930d8df3df46b306d03315d

Comment: Если кто то установит MiuiGallery.apk, функция будет врать.